# VLOOKUP and IF in multiple excel sheets

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

I have two excel sheets, as below, in a workbook

Sheet 1 & 2:

[image]

Below is the relation of fields between the two sheets

- EID is same as EmID
- DepID is same as DependentID
- DepDOB is same as DependentDOB

I would like to compare the EID with EmID. If match, do another compare on DepID with DependentID. If DepID is blanks, then compare DepDOB with DependentDOB. When all of this is true, get the DependentFirstName and DependentLastName from Sheet2 and copy it into a new column in Sheet 1.

Please see the image below for my intended result.

Output:

[image]

Please advise a method to achieve this. If VLOOKUP and IF has to be combined, please let me know the formula. This is giving me nightmares :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution as requested

A simple way to do this in the manner your requested is with helper columns.  Lets say sheet 1 looks like your output example, with columns A:F shown, and sheet 2 is also showing A:F.  Say we use column G for the helper column on each sheet.

The helper column concatenates the three comparison values.  So on each sheet, G2 would contain:

```
=A2&E2&F2
```

Copy the formula down the column on each sheet.  Then compare these values to find the record you need.

VLOOKUP requires that the lookup column be the leftmost in the array.  You can accomplish the same style of lookup using INDEX plus MATCH, which doesn't have this limitation. Sheet 1, C2 would contain:

```
=INDEX(sheet2!B:C,MATCH(G2,sheet2!G:G,0),1)
```

and in D2:

```
=INDEX(sheet2!B:C,MATCH(G2,sheet2!G:G,0),2)
```

Copy these down the column.  MATCH finds the key that matches the row on sheet 2 and returns the corresponding names.

[image: screenshot]

You can hide the helper columns if you don't want to see them.  If you're curious why the keys associated with a DepDOB don't look like a date it is because it uses the internal representation Excel uses to store the date.

#### Simpler solution

In this case, you have all the information you need to fill the first and last name fields already contained in the record.  Rather than using helper columns and lookups, you could just parse the DepName field.  C2 would be:

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1)
```

and D2 would be:

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(" ",B2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much fixer1234. That worked like a charm!! Appreciate it :)